# Title: How to Resolve the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'X' of undefined" Issue in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I have been struggling with a JavaScript error that keeps popping up in my code. I have already made some efforts to troubleshoot the issue, but I am unable to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

1. Checked for any typos or misspelled property names in my code.
2. Verified that all variables and objects I'm trying to access are initialized properly.
3. Reviewed the code multiple times to ensure that I haven't missed any brackets or parentheses.

Code Snippet:

```js
// Relevant code snippet where the error occurs
var obj = {
  // ...
};

function myFunction() {
  var value = obj.property.X; // Error occurs here
  // ...
}
```

Comment: means that `property` is undefined so clearly you have an issue. Hard to guess what the issue is with the provided code.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to use optional chaining to safely access nested properties in object.

```js
const obj1 = { prop1: { prop2: { } } };
```

Here if you try to access `obj1.prop1.prop2` it will be valid access since `prop1` & `prop2` exist. But if you try to access `obj1.prop2` // `obj1.someRandomPropName`  => it will lead to undefined. And on this if you try to access another property `obj1.someRandomPropName.nestedPropName` it will throw error since you trying to access a property on undefined which is not possible.

Solution:

Use optional chaining: `obj1?.prop1?.prop2?.prop3?.prop4`. I would recommend to use this only when you are not certain about property existence you are trying to access.

Answer (score 0):

Is your object property really named 'property'? Perhaps providing a code snippet or some kind of demo can help all of the people who want to help you.

Otherwise maybe you mean to invoke obj.(something else here, not property) and then .X(or maybe it is x? although you have mentioned you have checked spelling).